# Spring boot, Bootstrap is not rendering bootstrap style page

Tags: css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

I am making a spring boot mvc app using bootstrap and jsp,my app is running fine at other mappings, but on second levels like at url localhost:8080/admin/addSomething its rendering a simple html page instead of boot strap styled pages, can you suggest something ?
below is the path of my static resources

```
src/main/resources/static/public/css/customstyle.css/...

src/main/resources/static/public/lib/bootstrap/css/...

src/main/resources/static/public/lib/bootstrap/js/...

src/main/resources/static/public/lib/bootstrap/images/...

src/main/resources/static/public/lib/bootstrap/vendor/bootstrap/

src/main/resources/static/public/lib/bootstrap/vendor/font-awesome/...

src/main/resources/static/public/lib/bootstrap/vendor/jquery/...
```

I am new to bootstrap so I just copied the opensource template from google and using it.

after spending a long time to deal with the problem, I tried putting this in to my application.properties file

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=true
spring.resources.static-locations=/resources/
```

but when I add

```
spring.resources.static-locations=/resources/
```

then my other pages also stop showing bootstrap styles

also I tried this in my main application class

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

But nothing seems to work, can any one please suggest some solution ?

My jsp / html code on the page is fine, as it is showing desired look when i map its path to localhost:8080/addSomething

Answer (score 0):

How are the static resources linked in your JSP? they should start with a /, e.g. `/aa/bb.css`, and still better, you should use c:url, e.g. `<c:url value="/aa/bb.css" />`

Comment: Yes my resources are linked this way../public/...../style.css. some are linked as < c:url value=....> And some are with link href .... I guess this could be the problem. But why it's showing fine on first levels of mapping like on root or root / admin. Anyways will try it again by linking my jsps properly

Comment: Because, the application tries to grab the resource from the relative path. E.g. for a link "abc/xyz.css," if you are on first level, the relative path would become "http://localhost:8080/abc/xyz.css," which would be fine. But, if you are at "http://localhost:8080/admin", the path would become "http://localhost:8080/admin/abc/xyz.css," which is wrong. That's why you should always begin such links with a /.

Comment: Yes it did work, I forgot to put a "/" before public, so correct path should be <c:url value="/public/lib/bootstrap/....." />.  was trying to reply in comment earlier but my internet was down so couldnt reply.